# yii2 printing out data from table

Tags: php, arrays, activerecord, yii2

I have the following table

```
id name date_crated
1   first   2001
2   second  2002
3   third   2003
```

Now I'm getting data of the second row for example.

```
   $secondRow= testTable::find()
            ->where(['id' => 2])
            ->one();
```

But now I want to print out everything including the name of cells.
I mean I want to have access to everything.

So how can I print out `'id' , '2' , 'name', 'second' , 'date_created' , '2002'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply try something like this :

```
$data = [];
foreach ($secondRow->attributes as $name=>$value)
{
    $data[] = $name;
    $data[] = $value;
}
echo join(',', $data);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#$attributes-detail

Comment: editor says that $name->$value is undefined variable.
And even if I run this code I get 
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Cannot access empty property